# Where can I find the "One Minus" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have browsed all over Blender manual and nothing...

Comment: It's an ordinary math node that someone has closed and added a label to.  I would guess from the label that it's set up as a subtract node with 1 in the top box.

Comment: Leftclick on the node and press N. Then you can see the details and the node type on the right.

Comment: @AndréZmuda this is an ACTUAL answer to a question we get all the time, and maybe you should post it as one

Comment: You can also click the arrow to the left of the "One Minus" text which should expand the node and show what it contains.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention, I got only the image of the diagram, so cannot interact with it.
Curiously, this is the ONLY node I couldn't find, all the other ones (even hidden), had the right description in it.

Perhaps I should try to find the creator... :-/

Comment: It is 100% a math node set to 1.00 in the top field and mode set to subtract like @MartyFouts suggested. At least if the person who created it is a rational person :p

Comment: @Gorgious or they could be a user of RPN on HP calculators ;)

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 6):

As you only have the image, this node could be every node with two field inputs and one field output.

"One Minus" is just the label, that has been defined by the creator of the node net. As soon, as you define a label, the type of node is not displayed anymore.
The color of every node can be modified by the creator as well.

The diamonds mark the sockets as field sockets. And as they are grey, one can tell, that this are fields of seperate values and no vectors.

If you had the blend file, you could select the node and press N. Then you could see the details and the node type on the right.

Anyway - it is good practice to use a label that tells, what the node is doing. Therefore one could expect, that it is a math node, that substracts 1, as stated by @Marti Fouts.